# How can I understand $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, intuition, abelian-groups

This may be stupid request, but I would like to have a intuition for the group $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ in terms of 'real' objects. 'Real' could mean geometric but not necessarily. I perhaps what I'd like is to see it as a set of $\{0,1\}$-indexed integers and for the indices to somehow make 'real' sense.

If this intuition generalized to $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ it would be even better...

Comment: Well, you probably have $\mathbb Z/(12\mathbb Z)$ on your wall somewhere...

Comment: But maybe you have [other groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group) on your wall.

Comment: Is thinking of this group simply in terms of working in two groups $\mathbf{Z}$ and $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ simultaneously an unsatisfactory description?

Comment: @hurkyl I think I want something like an explanation for why I'm doing it. It's easy for the multiplication of natural numbers. When I'm multiplying them, I'm counting windows on a wall of a skyscraper, counting rows and columns. I would like something like this :)

Comment: @Bartek: You're counting pennies with one hand and sometimes flipping a switch with the other hand. You would use $\mathbf{Z}$ if you just paid attention to your first hand, and $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ if you only paid attention to your other hand. But you're paying attention to both!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how 'real' this is, but here's one way to visualise $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

There are two copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, call them $\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times\{1\}$.

$$\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}\qquad :\qquad \dots\qquad -3\qquad -2\qquad -1\qquad 0\qquad 1\qquad 2\qquad 3\qquad \dots$$

$$\mathbb{Z}\times\{1\}\qquad :\qquad \dots\qquad -3\qquad -2\qquad -1\qquad 0\qquad 1\qquad 2\qquad 3\qquad \dots$$

Pick two numbers from the lists. If both numbers belong to the same list, add them and take the corresponding number in the first list; if they belong to different lists, add them and take the corresponding number in the second list.

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to find find an application of this? That is, if you wanted to justify considering this operation to a non-math person, how would you do that?

Comment: Why do you think it is important to explain this particular group to a non-math person?

Comment: I'm the person :) I would like to have the interpretation to have a mental image of the groups.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple geometric interpretation. Consider the figure below, with marked fenceposts (or copies of the letter C) at every integer point on a horizontal line.

[image: Line with Cs at integer points]

Its group of symmetries is $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, generated by the horizontal translation and reflection across the horizontal.